# Unable to answer my phone call on mac

Tags: macos, facetime, continuity

Before recent OS and iOS upgrades I was able to answer calls on mac from my iPhone. Now, after recent upgrades i can only make calls from my Mac but I'm unable to answer them.

Whenever there is incoming call I receive notification on my Mac. When I click "Answer" after a second or two I'm presented with a message saying that there is no connection with my iPhone.

Network setup, FaceTime setup - everything is the same. The only thing that changed are OS and iOS versions.

```
Mac OS 10.13.1 (17B1003)
iOS 11.1.2 (15B202)
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the versions of iOS and macOS that you have?

Comment: @fsb added versions

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Disconnect both devices from Wi-Fi and Bluetooth. Restart both devices and then once they come back on try to reconnect them both (Wi-Fi on Mac - Wi-Fi on iPhone/ Bluetooth on Mac - Bluetooth on iPhone). If they successfully connect try to get someone to call you and see if the Mac picks it up. I do know that if your iPhone screen is on, or active sometimes the calls wont go to the Mac. Give that a try and then let us know the status.